# Uncaught TypeError: Tn.div is not a function at index-2659e1ee.js:128:48

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, vite, vercel, console.log

Uncaught TypeError: Tn.div is not a function at index-2659e1ee.js:128:48

var iS = Tn.div(sv(), function(e) {
var t = e.mobileBreakpoint;
return t
})

[enter image description here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv7DK.png)

printing-marketing-agency-kappa.vercel.app/

this is a live web app but not showing on the page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HewBs.png)

Comment: Please share any relevant code [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) by editing your Question. Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.